# Воспроизведение трекерной музыки *.xc на Android через FMOD

Tags: аудио, android, java

Друзья! Кто имел опыт работы с FMOD? доки из комплекта дистрибутива скучны... Даже примеров кода нету. Помогите кусочком кода плиз

Answer (score 1):

Обошелся библиотекой AndModPlug. Проста в юзанье